# CSS "Display:None" is leaving space on my portfolio page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using a wordpress site with OTW Portfolio Lite. I set it up so that any protfolio item that is password protected will be set to display:none

My CSS code:

```
.otw-portfolio li.post-password-required {
    display: none !important;
}
```

My HTML code:

```
<li data-id="id-test-portfolio-item" data-type="video " class="post-247 otw-portfolio type-otw-portfolio status-publish post-password-required hentry otw-portfolio-item">
     <article class="post-247 otw-portfolio type-otw-portfolio status-publish post-password-required hentry otw-portfolio-item" id="post-247">
    ...
    </article>
</li>
```

You can see what is happening here: http://www.studiobenna.com/portfolio/

Basically, I am getting a blank space where the password protected post is at (Between CDW and Cheetos Random). If I move it to the end by setting it to an older date it disappears but I need to be able to publish it any date and not have it appear. I think it has something to do with how the grid is setup but I am not sure how to fix it. Let me know if you have any ideas.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: by ID and no space `#post-247{ display: none!important;}` , please image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of this line:

```
.block-grid.three-up > li:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear: both;
}
```

You can just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting a width and height of 0 as well as the `display: none;`.